# In this RL circuit, why is the time constant independent of the resistor in parallel?

Tags: resistors, inductor, steady-state

[image]

I have to find the time constant of the above circuit.

I know that the time constant of this circuit without the resistive branch is \$\frac{L}{R}\$, but I'm unable to understand why the time constant is independent of the resistive branch.

Won't some current be drawn by the resistive branch affecting the rate at which steady state is obtained?

Comment: If you had a non-ideal voltage source then your concern would be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In \$1^{\text{st}}\$ order systems (RL or RC) the resistive part of the time constant is the Thevenin (or Norton) equivalent resistance from the point of view of the reactive element, in this case the inductor. When performing this circuit reduction, voltage sources are set to zero (short) as are current sources (open).

A slightly more complicated version of the circuit in question is shown in Figure 1.

Figure 2 shows the shorted voltage source and the inductor removed to facilitate the Thevenin resistance \$R_{\text{Th}}\$.

$$R_{\text{Th}}=R_{\text{2}}//R_{\text{3}}$$

\$R_{\text{1}}\$ is shorted out by the voltage source.

So the time constant is:
$$\tau=\frac{L}{R_{\text{Th}}}$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUjY50.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

It is independent because the voltage source in parallel means that the R has no effect.

The voltage source defines the voltages across your R&L; the additional R just means there is an additional load on the V source, but this does not affect the voltages at any node.

Answer (score 3):

The parallel resistive branch is also parallel to the voltage source. This renders it inconsequential to the analysis. You might just as well remove it in the analysis of time constant.

> *Won't some current be drawn by the resistive branch affecting the rate
> at which steady state is obtained?*

The current it draws will be constant (E/R) and not affect the current drawn by the RL branch.